# Surface integral of surface equation with more than two parameter

Tags: calculus

I need to do a surface integral of a parametric surface of the following form,

> $$\textbf{r}(u,v)=\langle\textbf{x}(u,v),\textbf{y}(u,v),\textbf{z}(u,v)\rangle$$

But the problem is both $u$ and $v$ are function of three other variable $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ and I want $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ as the integration variable. So the actual equation becomes like this,

> $$\textbf{r}(p_1,p_2,p_3)=\langle\textbf{x}(p_1,p_2,p_3),\textbf{y}(p_1,p_2,p_3),\textbf{z}(p_1,p_2,p_3)\rangle$$

I have found surface integral equations for the first kind of equation that I wrote. Can anyone please help me on how I can integrate the second kind of surface with $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ being the integration variable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Your second vector-valued function will have an image which is a volume and not a surface (assuming it's a continuous function over a compact domain). The domain is 3-dimensional and therefore so too will the image be 3 dimensional - I think, with the assumptions I've made in the parentheses. This is in stark contrast to single variable calculus. You can take many single variable, scalar-valued functions, and form compositions $h = f\circ g$ all day long. The domain of this composition and it's image are still 1-dimensional. However here, you took a

Comment: vector-valued function $r : D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ which would be a surface embedded in 3-space, and formed the composition $r \circ g$ where $g :\text{some subset of} \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. That is, $g$ is your $(p_1,p_2,p_3) \mapsto (u,v)$. Compositions in multivariable calculus have much more "geometric possibility". Just some thoughts